# Convert Array to Interface Array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

On an Angular 12 application I have the following environment:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  applications: [
    { name: "Api", url: "https://localhost:5001" },
    { name: "Bot", url: "https://localhost:5003"}
  ],
}
```

And I create an `Application` interface and `EnvironmentService` class:

```
export interface Application {
  name: string;
  url: string;
}

export class EnvironmentService {

  constructor() {}

  get production() : boolean { return environment.production; }

  get applications() : Application[] { return environment.applications };

}
```

But I get an error:

```
Type '{ name: string; url: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Application[]'.
```

How can I convert `environment.applications` to `Application[]`?

Comment: There is no JSON in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personaly i also describe my environment constant via interface. That way i can be sure that the constants for thedifferent environments will follow the same structure.

Therefore i would write it like:

```
export interface Application {
  name: string;
  url: string;
}

interface Environment {
  production: boolean;
  applications: Application[];
}

export const environment: Environment = {
  production: false,
  applications: [
    { name: "Api", url: "https://localhost:5001" },
    { name: "Bot", url: "https://localhost:5003"}
  ],
}

export class EnvironmentService {
  constructor() {}
  get production() : boolean { return environment.production; }
  get applications() : Application[] { return environment.applications };
}
```

With hard typing and no implicite "any", the IDE can give you all the help that you need.
Omiting a type is less work, and in rare occurances the code may be even more readable, but its also a lot easier to make mistakes.